# The word "only" in this sentence makes me feel uncertain

Tags: meaning

> > The extension of the principle of the reflex to include behavior involving more and more of the organism was made only in the face of vigorous opposition.

My understanding is this: the vigorous opposition is the reason why the principle of the reflex extend to include behavior involving more and more of the organism. But I'm not so sure about it, the word **only** in here seems to say vigorous opposition is the **only** reason, that doesn't make much sense.

The source is Skinner's "Science and human behavior" and following is the whole paragraph:

> > The extension of the principle of the reflex to include behavior involving more and more of the organism was
> >     made only in the face of vigorous opposition. The reflex nature of the spinal animal was challenged by proponents of
> >     a "spinal will." The evidence they offered in support of a residual inner cause consisted of behavior which apparently
> >     could not be explained wholly in terms of stimuli. When higher parts of the nervous system were added, and when
> >     the principle was eventually extended to the intact organism, the same pattern of resistance was followed. But arguments
> >     for spontaneity, and for the explanatory entities which spontaneity seems to demand, are of such form that they
> >     must retreat before the accumulating facts. Spontaneity is negative evidence; it points to the weakness of a current
> >     scientific explanation, but does not in itself prove an alternative version. By its very nature, spontaneity must yield
> >     ground as a scientific analysis is able to advance. As more and more of the behavior of the organism has come to be
> >     explained in terms of stimuli, the territory held by inner explanations has been reduced. The "will" has retreated up
> >     the spinal cord, through the lower and then the higher parts of the brain, and finally, with the conditioned reflex, 
> >     has escaped through the front of the head. At each stage, some part of the control of the organism has passed from a
> >     hypothetical inner entity to the external environment

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Read it as *the extension faced vigorous opposition* (but was ultimately made).

Comment: So you mean extension is the winner of the battle?

Comment: It certainly seems that way to me.

Comment: I think you are correct, it doesn't make much sense. It reads as if the opposition was the cause. Maybe it should  read as '.. only after facing vigorous opposition'.

Comment: If i have two statements:

1. "She opened the diary only to find out that ____ happened."

2. "She opened the diary to find out that only ____ happened."

Does that mean the first one doesn't make sense? I think they both have different meanings.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: "She opened the diary only in defiance of her stepmother". 'Only' is in a different idiom there than in ".. only to find a moth". So I agree with you, 'only' can be used in different ways. I think we all agree that in context, the face of opposition, if it had prevailed, would have prevented, not caused, the extension. "She opened the diary only with Jimminy's help" is the form I would expect, and Skinner's sentence does not fit that form.

Comment: Agree with you on it. Up-voted. :)

Comment: And maybe it is a Freudian slip on the part of Skinner, maybe he is admitting that, if the opposition had not existed, he would not have extended the reflex principle.

Comment: I don't think it is saying that opposition was the cause of the extension. It is saying that there was no extension of the principle *without* opposition. In other words, the opposition was there all the time, so 'with opposition' was the only form it took.

Comment: @RoaringFish. I see. Yes!

Comment: @RoaringFish. Well, except that "The extension.." is singular. If it were "Extension of the principle .." or "Any extension of the principle..", that would fit your reading exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Revised:*

The adverb ***only*** in this sentence is used as in definition 4A in the FreeDictionary:

> [***Only***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/only): *In the last analysis or final outcome:*

It modifies the verb *made*, and OP's sentence can be interpreted as:

In the final outcome, after some vigorous opposition had been overcome, the extension was made.

Comment: I didn't down-vote your answer, i don't think you are correct in your interpretation though. I have up-voted to acknowledge that you realize the significance of the attachment of 'only'.


IMHO, 'only' is neither attched to "made" nor to "opposition". It is attached to "in the face of", check my comment on the question to understand the difference with examples.

Comment: Read "The extension of the principle of the reflex to include behavior involving more of the organism was only accepted after overcoming vigorous opposition." Skinner's sentence is common idiom, but poor style, as the OP senses. Your answer is correct but not well-written. I suggest "modifies" instead of "attaches" in your answer. Maybe use the above re-write in your answer.

Comment: So the vigorous opposition is not cause but resistance, the word "only" is used to emphasize the fact that the opposition needs to be overcome before the extension was made?

Comment: "... only made after a big argument" is a poor sentence. It means "...only made (and nothing else) after a big argument." Written as "... was made only after a big argument (and after nothing else)" it makes more snse.

Comment: @RoaringFish, actually *only made after* and *made only after* is just a difference of word inversion and mean the same thing in my book.  No implication of 'and nothing else' is made here.

Comment: @ Jim - that may be the case in your book, but in the grammar book it is a case of what is being modified by 'only'.  Check it out in short here: http://www.lousywriter.com/grammar_mistakes_only_usage.php  or in a bit more detail here:  http://www.scribd.com/promuba/d/446134-The-use-of-ONLY

Answer (score 0):

Only in this case implies continuous.

> The extension of the principle of the reflex to include behavior involving more and more of the organism was made only in the face of vigorous opposition.

could be roughly restated as

Every attempt to extend the principle of the reflex to include behavior involving more of the organism was vigorously opposed.

At no point was it easy and there was vigorous opposition all the way up to the end.

Comment: There is the _contrasting_ of the bold move with the flak this engendered.   'The extension of the principle of the reflex to include behavior involving more and more of the organism _was_ made – but only in the face of vigorous opposition.' Longevity (of the opposition) isn't entailed by 'only'. // 'He swam ashore, only to be chased by a crocodile' (contrasting what one assumes would be a safe escape with actuality).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: yes, but the more and more implies a process or at least multiple passes, each of which had vigorous opposition.  So in this case I do see longevity of opposition and not a single surprise at the end.